# How do I convert JSON form data into a mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema: **Friend**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
...
var Friend = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String, age: Number });
```

When I send a request to `app.post("/friend/:name", ...)`,

`req.body.friend = { "name": "Steve", "age": "30" }`

All values are string and I want to them as their original schema data types:

`{ name: "Steve", age: 30 }`

I want to:

- not accept extra properties
- convert JSON string values to their type (e.g. "123" -> 123)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate the request object using  the [joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi) or [express-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator)package.

You must validate the request that is coming in your request body and params and serialise them when making db queries.

```
// validation_file.ts
import Joi from '@hapi/joi';

const userRequestObject = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string(),
    age: Joi.number()

})

// schema.validate({ name: 'abc', age: 14 });
export {userRequestObject };
```

use this in your express route. for eg -

```
//your_file.ts
import {userRequestObject} from "validation_file"
app.post("/friend/:name", validator.body(userRequestObject),),
```

Mongoose will throw error if datatypes are any particular key is not valid as you try to make any transaction.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything extra, provided you use `Friend.save({ // JSON Object })` to insert friend documents:

- Fields that are not in the schema won't get into the db
- By default, mongoose also helps you carry out typecasting during validation, so if you define a field as Number type in your schema, but a String was provided, mongoose would attempt to cast the String to a Number. You would need to handle possible errors that can occur due to typecasting here. [Source](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#cast-errors).